# ¿Porqué se genera el error "Unable to open web service tester page" en netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, webservice

Apache Tomcat está en "run" y al momento de hacer "Test Webservice" presenta el error
de la imagen. Por ello no genera el wdsl del web service, no funciona.

**Netbeans** es 8.2 en **Windows 7**  El contenedor web es Tomcat 7.0.41.0 y el JDK es 1.8.0
[image: ror]